# PHP : Dynamic Variable Passed Between Classes

Tags: php, class

My apologies if my title is not clear, please let me explain...

I have a template class call 'page', when I initialize it I can set it up to be in debug mode by setting $mode.

The problem is I also have a database class and I would like to share the fact that 'page' is in debug mode but don't know the best way to do it...I cannot have 'page' extends 'db' and no where does 'page' actually call the 'db' class.  It is always happening on other classes.

Again, sorry if this is unclear...I tried to provide a really simple version of the code to help...

```
class page {
    public $mode; // what mode the page is in (debug/normal)

    public function __construct($constructVars) {
        $this->mode = $constructVars["mode"]; //debug
    }

    public function debug($message){
        if ($this->mode == "debug"){
            $fh = fopen("debug.txt", 'a') or die("can't open debug file");
            fwrite($fh, date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." : ".$message."\n");
            fclose($fh);
        }
    }
}

class db extends PDO {
    public function debugOutput() {
        $page = new page();
        if ($page->mode == "debug"){
            $fh = fopen("debug.txt", 'a') or die("can't open debug file");
            fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
            fclose($fh);
        }
    }
 }
```

Just to reiterate because I think it is the answer that is going to come up, I can not extend page to include db.

Comment: share the fact that its in debug mode with whom?

Comment: What is the problem with the actual code?

Comment: You are correctly accessing the mode variable in the page class within your db class. Where are you having trouble getting the mode?

Comment: I am trying to share the page mode with db. The problem is, when I initialize the new 'page', it does not have the mode because it is different object than the main template 'page' object.

Comment: Why would a database need to know what mode a page is in? Is there only one page?

Comment: Not at all, when the page is in debug mode I want the db class to output debug info as well.

Comment: If that's the case, the debug mode is a state of the system from which the individual components are initialized.

Comment: Is this what they call "encapsulation"?

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass `$page` into `db::debugOutput()`:

```
class db extends PDO {
    public function debugOutput(page $page) {
        if ($page->mode == "debug"){
            $fh = fopen("debug.txt", 'a') or die("can't open debug file");
            fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
            fclose($fh);
        }
    }
}

$page = new page(array('mode' => 'debug'));
// ...
$db->debugOutput($page);
```

Comment: I got this working, thank you.  I was hoping to find a way to do it without passing parameters into db....that is to say, I was hoping there is a way to read $page->mode directly from the class into db.  I will keep checking this thread but I am assuming that is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a Static Class to store globally accessible stuff like this:

```
class SystemState{
    public static $debugMode = false; // what mode the page is in (debug/normal)
}

class page {

    public function __construct($constructVars) {
        if($constructVars["mode"] == 'debug'){
            SystemState::$debugMode = true;
        }
    }

    public function debug($message){
        if (SystemState::$debugMode){
            $fh = fopen("debug.txt", 'a') or die("can't open debug file");
            fwrite($fh, date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." : ".$message."\n");
            fclose($fh);
        }
    }
}

class db extends PDO {
    public function debugOutput() {
        if (SystemState::$debugMode){
            $fh = fopen("debug.txt", 'a') or die("can't open debug file");
            fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
            fclose($fh);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible to move the public static $debugMode into the class page and setup a static method to retrieve it from the db class?  Thanks for your help?  Obviously I don't understand fully the different class datatypes...I'm still pretty new to OOP.

Comment: i just saw i have a "mistake" in my answer: `$page = $new page()` isn't needed anymore in the `db` class

Comment: Static methods and Variable are bound to a Class itself while normal methods and variable always are bound to an instance of that class. Of course you could move that static variable to your page class and get/set that variable in a static manner like i did with the SystemState. You just would have to add the `public static $debug` to your page and then replace the `SystemState::$debugMode` with `Page::$debug` The page class can access it via `$this->debug` or `Page::->$debug`

Comment: THIS!!!! Thank you so much, this last post was exactly what I didn't understand.  I got it all working!!!  I would love to know why someone down voted you...so nice of them not to explain why.